# How to set autofocus on a matInput element on click event in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, html, angular-material

Similar to Google Login page, I want to have autofocus on input element after on click event. I have tried @ViewChild('id') and document.getElementId('id'). Both of it doesn't work. It's always null or undefined. How can I achieve this?

```
       <mat-form-field class="example-full-width col-sm-4">
        <input autofocus id="login-username" matInput 
       formControlName="userName" minlength="5" maxlength="20" 
       name="userName" placeholder="Username" required #input> 
      </mat-form-field>

        <div class="col-sm-12">
           <button (click)="changeView()" type="button" mat-raised-
             button color="primary">Next</button>
          </div>

         <mat-form-field class="example-full-width col-sm-4" 
          #passwordInput>
        <input autofocus type="password" matInput 
       placeholder="Password" minlength="5" maxlength="20" 
       formControlName="userPassword" #passwordInput>  
      </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Pl show some code from where in HTML you are referencing @ViewChild

Comment: I am declaring @ViewChild('passwordInput') before constructor and using it in the changeView() when called. like this.                                                                                  changeView(){
this.passwordInputRef.nativeElement.focus();                                                            } But this throws error. Says nativeElement is undefined.

Comment: ViewChild properties aren't set until the AfterViewInit lifecycle hook

Comment: you need to add a `timeout` before setting `focus()`, or it will throw `nativeElement` `undefined` error

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Unfortunately not every solution consistently works with autofocusing matInput at the moment of rendering. Here is what I tried:

- HTML `autofocus` attribute
- JS `input.focus()`
- `cdkFocusInitial` from `@angular/cdk`

All of the above methods might work but under some conditions they appear to be broken.

What **consistently** and **always** works is using a high-level api of the `matInput`. Here is a simple directive that uses this approach:

```
import { Directive, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatInput } from '@angular/material/input';

@Directive({
  selector: '[matInputAutofocus]',
})
export class AutofocusDirective implements OnInit {

  constructor(private matInput: MatInput) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => this.matInput.focus());
  }

}
```

The timeout is required to delay focusing the element because matInput does not properly function at the moment of creating yet. Usage:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input type="text" matInput matInputAutofocus>
</mat-form-field>
```

Of course, naming the selector `matInputAutofocus` is dangerous because material itself can come to this solution one day. Use it on your own risk or just rename with your prefix (recommended).

**Focus and meanwhile select the input value**

A cherry on the cake is adding the possibility to also preselect the content of the input (this is most of the time more user-friendly), which slightly changes the implementation:

```
import { Directive, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatInput } from '@angular/material/input';
    
@Directive({
  selector: '[matInputAutofocus]',
})
export class AutofocusDirective implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  autofocusSelectValue = false;

  constructor(
    private matInput: MatInput,
    private elRef: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.matInput.focus();

      if (this.autofocusSelectValue) {
        this.elRef.nativeElement.setSelectionRange(0, this.elRef.nativeElement.value.length);
      }
    });
  }

}
```

Use it as:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input type="text" matInput matInputAutofocus [autofocusSelectValue]="true">
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Another advantage of this solution over using accessing ElementRef using `<elementRef variable>.nativeElement.focus()` in `ngAfterViewInit()` is that you won't need to write ngAfterViewInit() for every component that uses `matInput` in it's template.

Comment: MatInput import should be:     import { MatInput } from '@angular/material/input';

Comment: @smnbbrv When I use this on an array of mat-form-fields created by a *ngFor-Loop, the focus is always set on the last element of the array. Do you have any idea how to fix that ?

Comment: @Phreneticus I guess the easiest is to add `@Input('matInputAutofocus') enabled: boolean;`, run the ngOnInit part only in case it is true, and in ngFor set the property to true if it is first (or another desired location), something like `<div *ngFor="let a of array; let first = first">...[matInputAutofocus]="first"`

Comment: Because this answer still works well, I'll add another suggested typo fix. Instead of `input.value.length`, you want `this.matInput.value.length`.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to set focus to an Input field as soon  as the page loads, you can do it simply by applying HTML attribute to that element, such as :

`<input type="text" #input1 autofocus>`

Else if you want to do this from your component.ts conditionally, use:

```
    import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild, AfterViewInit} from 
    '@angular/core';
    ... 

 @ViewChild('input1') inputEl:ElementRef;

 ngAfterViewInit() {
 this.inputEl.nativeElement.focus();
 }
```

Or you can use:

First import the renderer2 from @angular/core and then,

```
    const element = this.renderer.selectRootElement('#input1');

 setTimeout(() => element.focus(), 0);
```

Whatever you seems to be comfortable with your existing code.

Comment: Simples e Funcional!

Answer (score 9):

When you use Angular Material, you can use `cdkFocusInitial` to tell the library where you want to focus after component is ready. No native approaches are required:

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
  <mat-label>My Label</mat-label>
  <textarea 
    cdkFocusInitial           <---------
    cdkTextareaAutosize
    matInput>
  </textarea>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: This worked great for me.  Thank you!

Comment: what module should be imported to make this work?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [cdkFocusInitial](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#focus-management) from Material.

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="username" cdkFocusInitial>
</mat-form-field>
```

See [orginal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54230643/273602) answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use template ref to input element then use ViewChild it will work

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-frqm8b

```
 <mat-form-field class="example-full-width col-sm-4">
        <input autofocus id="login-username" matInput 
       formControlName="userName" minlength="5" maxlength="20" 
       name="userName" placeholder="Username" required #input> 
      </mat-form-field>

        <div class="col-sm-12">
           <button (click)="changeView()" type="button" mat-raised-
             button color="primary">Next</button>
          </div>

         <mat-form-field class="example-full-width col-sm-4" 
          >
        <input autofocus type="password" matInput 
        ****#passwordInput****
       placeholder="Password" minlength="5" maxlength="20" 
       formControlName="userPassword" #passwordInput>  
      </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a mixture of all the other answers. This was the only way it worked for me.

Add to any **Typescript** function

```js
  @ViewChild('foobarElement') foobarElement: ElementRef;
      
  anyFunction() {
      setTimeout(() => this.foobarElement.nativeElement.focus());
  }
```

And in the **HTML**

```
  <input type="text"
    matInput 
    #foobarElement>
```