# How to focus input element when Menu is opened?

Tags: angular, angular-material

[image]

```html
<button mat-button id="categories-button" [mat-menu-trigger-for]="categoryList">
  <span>categories</span>
  <mat-icon id="drop-arrow">arrow_drop_down</mat-icon>
</button>
<mat-menu #categoryList>
  <mat-form-field appearance="standard" id="category-search-wrapper">
    <input (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" matInput id="category-search">
  </mat-form-field>

  <button mat-menu-item>Settings</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Help</button>
</mat-menu>
```

I want `category-search` input to be focused, when Menu is opened, the problem is it doesn't seem to be ready yet, when menuOpened event is emitted. How can I focus input element when Menu is opened?

Comment: Since autofocus doesnt work, try out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51510936/how-to-set-autofocus-on-a-matinput-element-on-click-event-in-angular-6

Comment: The problem is ngOnInit will be called only once on page load and not on each menu open

Comment: But isn't the `mat-menu` not in DOM when its closed? If so, it should fire cause that directive will be initiated every time input is inserted into DOM, that is if.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Angular to provide an example, but all frontend frameworks have the concept of `tick()` / `nextTick(` that runs your code next time the DOM updates. It's a solve for this exact problem.

Answer (score 3):

```html
<button
  id="categories-button"
  [mat-menu-trigger-for]="categoryList"
  (menuOpened)="categorySearch.focus()"
>
  <span>categories</span>
  <mat-icon id="drop-arrow">arrow_drop_down</mat-icon>
</button>
<mat-menu #categoryList>
  <mat-form-field #categorySearch appearance="standard" id="category-search-wrapper">
    <input matInput (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" />
  </mat-form-field>

  <button mat-menu-item>Settings</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Help</button>
</mat-menu>
```

1. Add `(menuOpened)="this.categoryListOpened()"` to the button, that opens the Menu
2. Declare `categoryListOpened` method in your component's class like above

Answer (score 3):

you can use `ViewChild` as follow

```js
<button mat-button
  (menuOpened)="menuOpened()"
  [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu
</button>

<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <mat-form-field appearance="standard" id="category-search-wrapper">

    <input
      #search
      (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" matInput>

  </mat-form-field>

  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>


export class AppComponent  {

  @ViewChild('search', {static: false})
  inputElement: ElementRef;

  menuOpened() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.inputElement.nativeElement.focus();
    }, 0);
  }
}
```

[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-menu-autofocus?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Works great! also if the input is outside of the menu.

Comment: This works great for me too. However there is one small issue, if I type a letter in text box and if there is any mat-menu item (we have used button) starts with that letter, then the focus changes.
In above StackBliz example if I type "i" then focus changes as mat-menu contains Item1, Item2.
Any solution for this issue?